# Debugging Python extended on C++

Tags: python, c++

I am learning how to run Python through C++ and I'm having a hard time getting a handle on things. Is there a way to output the code that is generated by the various PyObjects? I'm not very experienced with embedding, so the documentation went a bit over my head.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about, but you might find [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/reference.html) useful in c++, rather than interacting with the python c-API directly.

Answer (score 2):

No, the PyObjects don't generate code -- it is just a c struct that holds the information of that particular Python object. You can inspect them in your C++ debugger.

I'm experienced with py embedding. The docs seem clear. Don't really get what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed clarification about what the PyObjects did. I hope my question didn't seem trite.